# How to Solve $\frac{\operatorname dy}{\operatorname dx}=\frac{{(x+y)}^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am a 12th  grader in India .
I am currently in my Differential Equations Course and
I am a beginner.
Can anybody help me in solving this Differential Equation.
I could nowhere find a solution on web .

Comment: Hint: put $$X=x+2,Y=y-2$$ becuse $x+y=x+2+y-2$

Comment: That Solved the question . I tried all sorts of Manipulations I could imagine and did not think about doing something  so simple.                                                                            Thanks

Comment: i am glad you are tried,ideally you could self answer this helps other people who may see the question and get their query answered

Comment: @Harsh Welcome to MSE. Learn about the [site and its features](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$$
Let $x-2=X, y-2=Y$, then
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{(X+Y)^2}{XY}$$
Let $$Y=VX \implies \frac{dY}{dx}=X\frac{dV}{dX}+V$$
$$\implies X\frac{dV}{dX}+V= \frac{(1+V)^2}{V} \implies X\frac{dV}{dX}=\frac{(1+V)^2}{V}-V  \implies \int \frac{VdV}  {1+2V}=  \int \frac{dX}{X}$$
$$\implies V=2\ln[CX(1+2V)^{1/4}], V=Y/X, X=x+2. Y=y-2$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        $$